# When rendering partial View it does not open inside Parent View in MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have just started to work on Mvc Framework, i want to display partial view which contains the product details.Main view contains the product Names on which user will click and the details of the product will be listed on the same page but my partial view is opening on the new page, the first time the page loads it displays by default the first product detail, i have tried a lot and seen other links but this problem remains the same.. please help to solve this. The complete code which i am using is listed below.

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
using MvcFirstMVCApp.Models;

namespace MvcFirstMVCApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        AuthorContactEntities dbEntities = new AuthorContactEntities();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(dbEntities.tbl_product.ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult PartialView(int id)
        {
            var query = dbEntities.tbl_product.First(c => c.ProductId == id);
            return PartialView("PartialView", query);
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model List<MvcFirstMVCApp.Models.tbl_product>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("div.product a").click(function (e) {
                alert("clicked");
                var url = this.ref;
                $get(url, {}, function (data) {
                    $('div.productdetail').html(data);
                });
            });
            return false; 
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="product">
        <ul class="list">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("PartialView", "Home", new { id = item.ProductId })">
                    @item.ProductName</a></li>
            }
        </ul>
        <div class="productdetail">
            @{Html.RenderPartial("PartialView",Model.FirstOrDefault());}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PartialView.cshtml

```
@model MvcFirstMVCApp.Models.tbl_product

<label>@Model.ProductDesc</label>
```

Author_Contact_DetailsModel.edmx

table Name:tbl_product

```
ProductId
ProductName
ProductDesc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour.

You are rendering a link to your action method here:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("PartialView", "Home", new { id = item.ProductId })">
                @item.ProductName</a></li>
```

Clicking that will make the browser navigate to your action method, which returns a Partial View. That Partial View has no Layout. It also appears that your View doesn't have a layout either.

This is going to sound harsh.. but you should revisit your MVC resources and re-read up on how Partial Views work. They aren't magical dynamic loading views.. if thats what you want you need to investigate AJAX.

Comment: Can you please give me link of such types of question or tutorials... thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.product a").click(function (e) {
    var url = this.ref;
    $get(url, {}, function (data) {
        $('div.productdetail').html(data);
    });
    // Return here to prevent click event from opening new page
    return false;
});
```

By clicking the anchor tag, you open a new page which renders your partial view. You need to prevent the default behavior of anchor.

You can add `return false;` to do that.

Comment: i have added return false but still it is redirecting to a seperate partial view page..

Answer (score 0):

call e.preventDefault(); in the onclick handler:

```
$("div.product a").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("clicked");
            var url = this.ref;
            $get(url, {}, function (data) {
                $('div.productdetail').html(data);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Using e.preventDefault() does not show the product details and neither it redirects to another page.

Answer (score 0):

See this post.  Adding one line of code in the _layout, as suggested, solved this issue for me.

Post: [MVC4 Kendo Project Ajax.BeginForm UpdateTargetId Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712972/mvc4-kendo-project-ajax-beginform-updatetargetid-issue)